# Function inside a class not triggering

Tags: angular, function, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm experimenting with different ways of implementing Typescript classes and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get my function to work properly.

So far this is what I have:

**calc-func.ts :**

```
export function calcFunc( a: number, b: number ){ return a*b; }
```

**callc-class :**

```
import { calcFunc } from './calc-func';

export class CalcClass implements calcFunc {
  NumA: number = null;
  NumB: number = null;
  NumC: number = calcFunc( this.NumA, this.NumB );
}
```

**app.component :**

```
export class App implements OnInit {

    Calculation: CalcClass = new CalcClass();

    ngOnInit(){
      this.Calculation.NumA = 3;
      this.Calculation.NumB = 7;
   }
}
```

**app.component (template) :**

```
 <h2>number = {{Calculation| json}}</h2>
```

`NumC` is showing up as 0 instead of 21 even though `NumA` is showing up as 3 and 'NumB' shows up as 7 as I'm aiming for.

What else do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `NumC` is initialized when the `CalcClass` object is created, and it is not updated after that. If you want `NumC` to call `calcFunc` each time you access it, you should define it as a property:

```
get NumC(): number {
    return calcFunc(this.NumA, this.NumB);
}
```